# How to unite() and show asterix with values for significance within dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this df with a lot of coefficients in one column and asterixs in the next column. I am trying to unite() the two columns but i get an error. I made an example:

```
library(dplyr)
# creating df
df <- tibble(city = c("amsterdam", "amsterdam", "amsterdam", "rotterdam", "rotterdam", "rotterdam"),
                terms = c("intercept", "food", "service", "intercept", "food", "service"),
                coefficient = c(23, .54, -.02, 18, .86, .67),
                p.value = c("***", "*", " ", "***", "***", "**"))

# Here i try to unite the two columns
df %>% 
  mutate(coefficient = unite(coefficient, p.value, sep = ""))
```

When i run this i get the following error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: no applicable method 
for 'unite_' applied to an object of class 
"c('double', 'numeric')".
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this? If possible also it would be nice if the final column is aligned in such a way that the minus sign starts earlier than the numbers in the final column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unite` is meant to be used as a stand alone function, it is expecting a data frame as its first argument, and returns another data frame (which is not `mutate` is expecting) see `?unite`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% unite(col = coefficient, coefficient, p.value, sep = "")

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#       city     terms coefficient
#*     <chr>     <chr>       <chr>
#1 amsterdam intercept       23***
#2 amsterdam      food       0.54*
#3 amsterdam   service      -0.02 
#4 rotterdam intercept       18***
#5 rotterdam      food     0.86***
#6 rotterdam   service      0.67**
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.6.3/topics/unite) I see that unite is a "convenience function to paste together multiple columns into one." So I assume you are just trying to paste the columns together? In that case you could do:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(coefficient = paste0(coefficient, p.value))

       city     terms coefficient p.value
      <chr>     <chr>       <chr>   <chr>
1 amsterdam intercept       23***     ***
2 amsterdam      food       0.54*       *
3 amsterdam   service      -0.02         
4 rotterdam intercept       18***     ***
5 rotterdam      food     0.86***     ***
6 rotterdam   service      0.67**      **
```